# Aiogram 3. Как научить бота понимать значения кубика dice?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

После перехода с aiogram 2 на 3, перестал нормально работать код, конкретно бот больше не понимает значения кубика и что нужно делать если значение одно больше другого и наоборот.

Ошибка - cannot access local variable 'bot_data' where it is not associated with a value

Код:

```
@dp.message(Command("game"))
async def handler_game(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Поехали, @{message.from_user.username}!")
    
    await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    bot_data = bot_data["dice"]["value"]
    
    await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    user_data = user_data["dice"]["value"]
    
    if bot_data > user_data:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы проиграли!")
    elif bot_data < user_data:
       await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы победили!")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Запускай снова!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря коллегами из aiogram сообщества в тг, ребята мне помогли и на версии 3.1.1. Необходимо писать так:

```
 msg = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    value = msg.dice.value
    await sleep(2)
    
    msg = await bot.send_dice(message.from_user.id)
    value2 = msg.dice.value
    await sleep(3)
    
    if value > value2:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы проиграли!")
    elif value < value2:
       await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы победили!")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Запускай снова!")
```